# ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am using custom log4j2 library - corporate library, company specific, I created fat jar out of maven project and trying to run the code commandline

```
java -jar "target\abc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
FATAL AlertPocDemo SomePOCData
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>netcool-demo-inbuilt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>netcool-poc</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
        <log4j-tcs.version>2.17.0-tcs-patch-4</log4j-tcs.version>
        <netcool.version>1.3.1</netcool.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>XXX.YYY</groupId>
            <artifactId>Log4j2NetcoolSocketAppender</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0-tcs-patch-4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>XXX.ef.AlertPocDemo</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>XXX.ef.AlertPocDemo</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
                <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>one-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>XXX.ef.AlertPocDemo</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <dependencyReducedPomLocation>${java.io.tmpdir}/dependency-reduced-pom.xml</dependencyReducedPomLocation>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.acme.coyote</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>hidden.coyote</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I suspect (so not an answer) that `<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>` is removing some reflection-loaded class that's used by Log4J. Try removing that line and see what happens. Otherwise, your locally-repackaged `log4j-core` is missing something important. Try with the "real" dependency to see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see a solution [here](https://github.com/fbacchella/LogHub/blob/master/pom.xml). It works for me

```
<filter>
    <artifact>log4j:log4j</artifact>
    <includes>
        <include>org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent.class</include>
    </includes>
</filter>
<filter>
    <artifact>org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-*</artifact>
    <includes>
        <include>**</include>
    </includes>
</filter>
```